# Extending or adding new classes at runtime in Java

Tags: java, class, runtime, extend

Is there a way to add (or extend existing) classes at runtime in java. I'm stuck on a problem, in which I have to extend an existing class at runtime and add this to the classpath, so that this new class get picked up.

thanks,

Answer (score 12):

There are a number of ways you could do this.

- Compile source code at runtime using the [javax.tools](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html) package and then load them using a [ClassLoader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html).
- If you are writing to interfaces, you can decorate classes with a [Proxy](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).
- Take the more complicated route of bytecode manipulation/generation using a technology like [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/index.html) or [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) (the latter has more up-to-date support for language features, like annotations) and then load the class with a ClassLoader.

I imagine there are other options.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/index.html). Without any more information about what you need to do, it's tricky to give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely write why you need this feature.
If you attempt to add or replace logic at runtime you might want to have a look at the [scripting API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html) and some actual [implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_scripting_languages).