# Meta Model library for Java Programs

Tags: java

Maybe someone here knows a library that does what I need since I can't find any library that really does this stuff but I am certain that this has been done before.

So basically I'd like to have a library that can read in entire projects or just one .java file at a time and then gives me some kind of meta model of the class(es).

So basically something like

```
MetaClass c = MetaParser.parse(X.java);
MetaMethod[] methods = c.getMethods();
MetaAttribute[] attributes = c.getAttributes();

System.out.println("Class " + c.getClassname() + " has " + methods.length + " methods.");
```

So I can analyze that class by getting all Methods, all Attributes and so on. Basically like an object-oriented representation of that class in some way.

Comment: Why not to use `java.lang.reflect`? Seems like it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is mentioned in the comments. Here is a more detailed example of how you can use it to achieve what you want:

Let's suppose you have the class `Main` you want to know more about:

You can get the package of the class:

```
Main.class.getPackage().getName();
```

The methods of the class:

```
Method[] methods = Main.class.getDeclaredMethods();
Method[] pMethods = Main.class.getMethods(); //only gets the public methods
for(Method m: pMethods) { //print methods and their parameters
   System.out.println("Method " + m.getName() + ", with parameters: ");
   Arrays.asList(methods[0].getParameters()).forEach(p -> System.out.print(p.getName()+","));
}
```

Constructors similarly:

```
Constructor<?>[] constructors = Main.class.getConstructors();
```

You can even create objects with them. For fields, there is

```
Field[] fields = Main.class.getDeclaredFields();
Field[] pFields = Main.class.getFields(); //only public fields
```

As for how can you actually add the class you want to inspect at runtime, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011443/extending-or-adding-new-classes-at-runtime-in-java) question for example.

Answer (score 0):

if you intend to analyze **compiled** code (bytecode, *.class files) then Gtomika's answer above is correct - the standard reflection API is good enough to get started.

if, however, you want to analyze java **source code** (*.java files) i'd recommend a library like [javaparser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser)