# Can I add a new child class at run time?

Tags: java, reflection

I need to add the following class at run time:

```
public class MapperFunction extends Mapper<Integer, String, String, Integer> {


    public MapperFunction(InputBlock s) {
        super(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected void map(Integer key, String value) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
        Matcher matcher;
        String str = value;
        if (!str.equals("")) {
            matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                String word = matcher.group();
                if (!MapperOut.containsKey(word))
                    MapperOut.put(word, 1);
                else
                    MapperOut.put(word, (Integer) MapperOut.get(word) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or add the method map() to class during run time. I read the following question on stackoverflow [Extending or adding new classes at runtime in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011443/extending-or-adding-new-classes-at-runtime-in-java)
 but I think my case differs a bit, anyway this is the parent class Mapper:

```
public abstract class Mapper<keyIn, valueIn, keyOut, valueOut>  implements Runnable {

    private RecordReader recordReader;
    static AtomicInteger numberOfThreadsPerMapper = new AtomicInteger(2);
    static Map<Object, Object> MapperOut = null;

    static {
        MapperOut = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<>());
    }

    Mapper(InputBlock s) {
        recordReader = new LineRecordReader(s);
    }

    protected abstract void map(keyIn key, valueIn value) throws IOException, InterruptedException;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        run2();
    }

    public void run2() {
        try {
            while (recordReader.hasNext()) {
                map((keyIn) recordReader.getKey(), (valueIn) recordReader.getValue());
            }
            //   System.out.println("Thread out." + numberOfThreads.getAndIncrement());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the parent class Mapper extends Thread.

My second question: if I can do that how can I create instance from it? Now this my call to create:

```
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

        executorService.submit(new MapperFunction((InputBlock) arg));
    }
```

My last question: if all that can happen is there any disadvantage (performance issue) since the application creates more instances from MapperFunction class()?

Comment: "i think my case different a bit" - why?

Comment: Your code doesn’t use Reflection and there’s no recognizable reason why you are even thinking about Reflection. Further, there is no instance of `Mapper`, as `Mapper` is an abstract class. In the code you’ve shown, you create exactly one instance of `MapperFunction`. Besides that, you should not extend `Thread` when you only want to create a `Runnable` to be passed to `submit`. Just use `implements Runnable` instead of `extends Thread`.

Comment: Further, there’s no reason for this redundant initialization,  `static Map<Object, Object> MapperOut = null;

    static {
        MapperOut = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<>());
    }`, just initialize the variable with the intended expression in the first place, i.e. `static final Map<Object, Object> MapperOut = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<>());`

Comment: But using `synchronizedMap` alone is not always sufficient for thread safety; your code `if (!MapperOut.containsKey(word)) MapperOut.put(word, 1); else MapperOut.put(word, (Integer) MapperOut.get(word) + 1);` is subject to the check-then-act anti-pattern. After the execution of `containsKey(word)`, the condition may change before one of the `put` statements is executed, further, `MapperOut.put(word, (Integer) MapperOut.get(word) + 1);` does it again, performing one action, `get`, then performing a `put` based on that value when it could be outdated already. `merge` is your friend here…

Comment: @Holger i'm so thankful for this advice, [there’s no recognizable reason why you are even thinking about Reflection?] basically the user should write the code through GUI,(if u have any other idea plz let me now).[there is no instance of Mapper] yeah thank i  fix it thans. [you create exactly one instance of MapperFunction] im using Observer pattern so update will should be called many time, [Just use implements Runnable] i did thanks dude :) , [no reason for this redundant initialization] i will fix it,

Comment: [ synchronizedMap alone is not always sufficient or thread safety] what is merge is take 2 many time to understand? i'm beginner :(

Comment: @Holger is there any easy way to make it thread safe?

Comment: You can use `merge` to replace the entire `if (!MapperOut.containsKey(word)) MapperOut.put(word, 1); else MapperOut.put(word, (Integer) MapperOut.get(word) + 1);` logic. If the map declaration was `Map<Object,Integer>`, you could simply use `MapperOut.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);`. The advantage is that this is a single operaration, so for a synchronized map, no other thread can step in-between, which makes it safe. Since you have a `Map<Object,Object>`, you need type casts, e.g. `MapperOut.merge(word, 1, (a,b) -> (Integer)a + (Integer)b);` (something like that, not tested)